# Two RecyclerView below CoordinatorLayout

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm tring to insert two RecyclerView inside a RelativeLayout below my CoordinatorLayout.

This is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="30dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="50dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="30dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>    

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout> 

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/details"
        layout="@layout/adapter_details"/>      

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/details"/>   

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/recycler_view"/> 

    </RelativeLayout>               

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>   

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When i execute the app the second RecyclerView, recycler_view2, not appears. Why? How can i solve it?

Comment: What did you already tried? Please provide more information.

Comment: What are you populating on recycler view and two..

Comment: @Odrai: simply i tried to populate the two RecyclerViews with an ArrayList of custom object (@Moulesh), but recycler_view2 doesn't appear, while recycler_view yes.

Comment: Use nestedScrollview for multiple recycle view and wrap_content height for each recycleview

Comment: @bond007: NestedScrollView can only host one direct child

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try 

   <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical">
   <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical">



    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/details"/>   

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/recycler_view"/> 

  </LinearLayout>

         </ScrollView>

     </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```